# Modelling a spiral around a sphere

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to figure out the best way to model the sphere-spiral here:

[image]

Is it possible to make this shape directly? Or do you have to make it as a cylinder and wrap it to a sphere?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok... I can't help putting out the laziest of the answers...

Enable the **Add Curve: Extra Objects** plugin.

[image]

Then do Add->Curve->Spirals

[image]

Select spiral type number 3 (spheric), and give it the parameters you want for radius, turns, etc:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to model this is to shrinkwrap a strip of vertices to a sphere and then put a skin modifier on it.

I would recommend starting out with two verts, one at the origin and the other about twenty units up the x-axis and about two units up the z-axis. Once you have the verts in place, subdivide it with about 400 cuts and add a simple deform modifier. Switch the modifier to Bend mode and jack the angle way up to around 2560. This will give you a corkscrew shape.

[image]

Try to get it looking something like this. If you didn't quite get it right, you can set the transform pivot from Median Point to 3D Cursor in the bottom bar. Then, you can scale along the Z axis to make the corkscrew shape taller, or along the X axis to make it skinnier/fatter.

Then, make a new UV sphere subdivided a couple more times from the default and fit it inside the corkscrew shape you got, and add a Shrinkwrap modifier to the corkscrew. Set the mode to Nearest Surface Point (you can't use Project because there aren't any faces.)

[image]

At this point you will probably want to apply the simple deform modifier, go into edit mode, set the pivot to the 3d cursor, put the cursor on the bottom of the sphere, turn proportional editing on in Connected mode, set the falloff to sharp, and scale down the vertex on the bottom locking the Z axis. Do the same for the vertex on the top to get the shape kind of close to the sphere shape. (I recommend having the shrinkwrap modifier display on the edit cage to make this easier to see.)

[image]

Once you've done that, add the skin modifier, check Smooth Shading, and scale down the skin radius with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. Put a subdivision surface modifier on that and you've got your weird corkscrew sphere thing. Here's mine:

[image]

Comment: Hi, looks like you've got a decent answer going, but it's really hard to follow, and intimidating to read because of not having any line breaks. Could you clean it up a bit please?

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll get it done in a bit.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a script to produce a Spherical Spiral  [Loxodrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line) , from it's [parametric equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalSpiral.html)

```
import bpy

from mathutils import Vector
from math import radians, sin, cos, tan, sqrt, floor

context = bpy.context

def loxodrome_points(spirals, revs, angle_step=10):
    a = 1 / spirals
    degs = floor(360 * revs / 2)
    segs = [radians(d) for d in range(-degs, degs, angle_step)]
    points = []
    for t in segs:
        den = sqrt(1 + a * a * t * t)
        x = cos(t) / den
        y = sin(t) / den
        z = - a * t / den
        l = Vector((x, y, z))
        points.append(l)     
    return points
       
       
points = loxodrome_points(10, 10)
#loxodrome = bpy.data.objects.get("Loxodrome")
#if loxodrome is None:
if True:
    loxocurve = bpy.data.curves.new("loxo", 'CURVE')
    loxocurve.dimensions = '3D'
    loxocurve.resolution_u = 2
    spline = loxocurve.splines.new('NURBS')
    spline.points.add(count=len(points) - 1)
    
    for i, bp in enumerate(spline.points):
        x, y, z = points[i]
        bp.co = (x, y, z, 1)
        
    loxodrome = bpy.data.objects.new("Loxodrome", loxocurve)    
    context.collection.objects.link(loxodrome)
```

Produces a unit radius curve  Loxodrome at (0, 0, 0) applying the matrix_world of a sphere to the loxodrome curve should see it remain on surface.  Adjust the parameters in `loxodrome_points(10, 10)` for differing 'dromes.

[image]

Comment: How can I scale the spiral or make it bigger?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

A variety of spirals can be constructed. Equal width (involute), great circles and so on.The Loxodrome on sphere given below is made with above equations on Mathematica.

[image]

Comment: What's this supposed to mean? Was this meant to be a comment?

Comment: Please add some information as to how the user might be able to use this information. As it is, it is not clear how a user might implement this equation.

Comment: Added to my answer re that the Spherical Spiral is a special case of a loxodrome, in that the crossed meridians are those of a sphere.  Also added  link to wolfram page with equations used.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot I am very new to Blender. Equations of curves and surfaces  can be coded and shown in Mathematica.