# Closing "Fibonacci's Hole"

Tags: python, mesh, geometry, bmesh, mathematics

Creating a sphere using the points defined by [Spherical Fibonacci Mapping](http://lgdv.cs.fau.de/uploads/publications/spherical_fibonacci_mapping.pdf).  For the most part it is easy to "skin" by using two consecutive fibonacci numbers as steps to loop on the index. And get results similar to
[image]
Here is what I have so far
[image]
*Edges made by stepping thru verts with 8th Fibonacci number 21 and  9th; 34.*

The hassle comes around the poles, so I stopped short leaving a leaflike pattern hole.

The select verts in the image are those that have 3 faces and 4 edges.

```
verts = [ v for v in bm.verts 
          if len(v.link_faces) == 3 
          and len(v.link_edges) == 4]
```

For each of these verts there is a rip. (the two edges with only one face)

```
split_edges = [q for e in v.linked_edges 
               for q in e.verts
               if len(q.linked_edges) == 2]
# sort by length
split_edges.sort(key=lambda a:-a.calc_length())
```

The desired result will close that split at the selected vert leaving a "T" 3 edge vert with the caveat of leaving the vertex in place. (As it is a member of SF space).

I was hoping to be able to swap the verts from one BMedge to another, but alas...

What other methods are available other than removing two edges adding one and a face?

The spherical fibonacci code can be found here https://gist.github.com/batFINGER/64db074e95b716f839a71882b7efcc50

The sample mesh in q can be generated using:

```
scene = context.scene
n = 1024
# create a point mesh
sfmesh = SFBMesh(n)
#sfmesh.edge()
# make mesh using 9th and 10th fibonacci numbers       
k = 9
bm = sfmesh.bm
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
for i in [k, k + 1]:
    fib = F(i)
    print("Fib number ", i, fib)
    start = fib - F(i-2)
    start = 2
    edges = [bm.edges.new([bm.verts[i] for i in [k, (k + fib) % n]]) for k in range(start, n - fib - 2)]
#bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=verts)
bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=bm.edges)
faces = [f for f in bm.faces if len(f.verts) > 4]
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=faces, context=5)
meshdata = sfmesh.mesh
goldie = bpy.data.objects.new("SF", meshdata)   
scene.objects.link(goldie)
scene.objects.active = goldie
goldie.select = True
```

Comment: If you wanted to do it manually, how does it look like ?

Comment: Something like d or e in http://i.stack.imgur.com/Og9J5.png

Comment: Calling `sfmesh.edge()` gives a result something close-ish to (f).

Comment: There is an addon called sverchok which can generate mathematically based meshes you can give it a try i guess.

Comment: this question seem too technical and would take a lot of time to get into for most users. If you add some explanations, more users will be able to help. Which "hassle" came round the pole? You say you "stopped short", what do you mean by that? How did you come up with the expression to create edges? Because vertices seem to be perfectly fine.

Comment: generally some context will help. It is hard to find connection between what's written in your code and what is in the paper. As far as I see the paper deals with a problem: given a point on a sphere, find closes point from Fibonacci point set. Then there comes a heap of non-trivial maths. Where exactly is the connection with your mesh problem?

Comment: I would like to skin the fibonacci points with quads, without a pole > 5 edges.  Using at least the points from the code provided.

Comment: Well, that's problematic. You said you want it like on the picture, but on the picture the pole has lots of edges coming to it and not all are quads.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding.  If you look at the pic above (blender screenie) and close the "rips" at the selected verts by moving longest edge to shortest, you will start to turn around the spirals and can try and maintain a squarer face.

Answer (score 13):

Oh gosh, I spent ages with it. On the pictures you posted it looks particularly nice because of lines are actually spirals. If they were straight it won't look nice. On your picture pole doesn't have quads and also has a lot of adjacent edges. So if you don't want this, maybe you can just stop (I would stop earlier) and connect the rest of the points using a different triangulation method?

In your implementation there is same distance of `fib` between each pair of vertices you connect. So the question comes when index + `fib` is larger than number of vertices. Where do you want to connect the rest of them?

This is what I get for k = 7. 
[image]

And this for k = 9.

[image]

This is the bit I changed. But I am no expert in either `bmesh` nor `bpython`, so maybe you can polish it.

```
# make mesh using 9th and 10th fibonacci numbers       
fibk = 7
bm = sfmesh.bm
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
for i in [fibk, fibk + 1]:
    fib = F(i)
    print("Fib number ", i, fib)
    for k in range(-fib+1, n-1 ):
        for i in [k, min(n-1,k + fib)]:           
            try:
                bm.edges.new([bm.verts[max(0,k)],bm.verts[min(n-1,k + fib)]] )      

            except(ValueError):
                print('duplicate')
```

1) Also you can find code  [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/sphere_grid/sphere_grid.html) which produces this, maybe it will be useful. 
[image]

2) Also look at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59061/fibonacci-point-on-a-sphere) post which leads to this solution:
[image]

It seems there are in general **not many ways** to make a nice quad mesh of a sphere.No matter how you do it, there always is going to be a seem. I think 1) and 2) two are basically the main solutions.

Bo, if you want Fibonacci I would go with 2),so cut it off and close it as they did, if you want regular - with 1).

Comment: Yep spent too much time on it too.. here's where I got to. https://gist.github.com/batFINGER/64db074e95b716f839a71882b7efcc50#gistcomment-1878756  On doing it with a numbers approach on the index got a hunch that when you get near poles (index < 21 for fib(8) and zero pole) need to step down in fib numbers that sum to that index.

Comment: @batFINGER essentially you want a Delaunay triangulation and a smart way of merging pairs of triangles for the case of this Fibonacci whatever mesh. So for the middle it seems smart enough to merge them like it is now, but there is a point where this Fibonacci step is not giving you nearest neighbour any more (which Delaunay does)

Comment: @batFINGER wait, can't you just stop before this starts happening and sort of rotate your sphere 90 degrees, so that the poles are at the equator? And use the same sort of meshing as now, which looks good at the equator.

Comment: @batFINGER in fact, this image looks like diving it in 3 bits of 120 degrees and having a seem in between.