# how can, I make this hole with array modifier?

Tags: modifiers

How can I make this hole shape like this image?
[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason about using an array modifier?

Comment: and [Spiral array but with fibonacci sequence](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170482/spiral-array-but-with-fibonacci-sequence)