# How to make a Zoetrope out of a single mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, 3d-printing

Can anyone explain how to go about making a 3D printable [Zoetrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoetrope)?

Unlike any other zoetrope I've seen, each of these are a single, spinning mesh rather than a series of similar objects in a circle. Is there a modifier or addon for creating such a model?

Comment: Look into the [tissue addon.](http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue)

Comment: Below video you have set of links, check this one: http://www.instructables.com/id/Blooming-Zoetrope-Sculptures/ "These blooms were modeled using Python scripting for Rhino on a Mac."  You have there many pictures of how to made them.

Comment: @cegaton I don't think Tissue will help here as shape is pretty irregular: https://cdn.instructables.com/F5Y/L5MC/I0R13A9K/F5YL5MCI0R13A9K.MEDIUM.jpg and from my expierience with it it doesn't allow to make such forms.

Comment: I think those question will answer yours: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/organic-yet-accurate-modeling-with-the-golden-spiral and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59061/fibonacci-point-on-a-sphere