# How do you make a spiral?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I need to make a little spiral for a model I'm making you know those little things on the handle of a furnace

[image: this little thing right here]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/modelling-a-spiral-around-a-sphere

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do this with a *Bezier Curve* object.

There is a builtin addon shipped by default with Blender that allows drawing spiral objects. You can activate it under the *File > User Preferences > Addons > Add Curve: Extra Objects*.

Then on the 3D View add a new curve type object, from *Add Curve:Spirals > Archemedian*

Adjust paremeters to your liking, more importantly *Height*, *Radius* and *Number of Turns*. You can also use *Radius Growth* although I fear it is insufficient alone.

After creating your base spiral, you can enter *Edit Mode* in it, activate *Proportional Edit* , select a buch of spiral loops as desired and use scaling to change the radius into that smooth shape.

Be sure to use <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to restrict scaling to the XY plane, so it will only make the loops thinner/fatter, without moving them in Z axis.

[image]

Comment: I went into user preferences and added the extra curves but there is no option to add an archemedian curve

Comment: Try `Shift + A` > *Add > Curve > Add Curve:Spirals > Archemedian* in the 3D view. Make sure you are not in edit mode under another object.

Comment: Is it supposed to be like a little sub menu thing?

Comment: It is under a submenu, check the included screenshot in my answer.

Comment: I can't see any screenshots I'm on a school laptop also i don't see any sub menus under spirals

Comment: There is an animated GIF in my answer illustrating the process, can't you see it?  Check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzIgy.gif