# How to Taper a coil?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, screw-modifier

I created a simple coil/spring using the "Screw" modifier. Is there a way to "taper" the coil so it gets smaller on one end?

Explanation: I created an Xmas tree in Blender. Now I want to add a string of lights to it using a coil. Hopefully it's something that can be done easily.

PS: I'm using v2.79. Still learning/hate v2.80.

My coil:
[image: Simple coil]

Comment: Some more similar info available here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300548/how-can-i-make-a-half-circle-spiral-slide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me propose another solution.
This will get you the christmas tree shape.

It's not perfect, but it's fast.

1) Create a spring using the *Screw modifier*.
2) Add a *SimpleDeform* modifier, set mode to *Taper*,  set axis to *Z*
3) Adjust the *Deform Factor* to change the diameter of the spring.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's perfect and fast!

If you want to create this shape and don't want to deform the pipe, you could do it this way:

- Activate the addon called *Add Curve: Extra Objects* (available by default in Blender). Create a *Curve* > *Curve Spirals* > *Archemedian*.

[image]

- In the operator panel, find the right setting.

[image]

- In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > Give your curve a *Fill* > *Full*, choose the *Bevel Depth* and the *Resolution* you want. Convert to mesh if needed.

[image]

Comment: Very nicely tapered coil/spring indeed.

Comment: Do I remember correctly that this primitive is only available if you enable an add on?

Comment: Yes you're right I'm going to edit

Answer (score 4):

Use a [Bezier curve spiral](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79436/how-do-you-make-a-spiral/79439#79439) instead the use the *Radius Property* to control the tapering.

After adding the spiral enter *Edit Mode* turn on *Proportional Edit* and use the [Radius Property](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/58567#58567) to control the tapering.

Select the tip vertex then press<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to change curve radius, use the <kbd>Mousewheel Scroll</kbd> to control the influence radius.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it wasn't the tip I needed to taper but the entire coil (top-to-bottom.) Fortunately, I believe I already found the solution: With my coil selected and placed over my tree, I found a "taper" modifier as part of the "Simple deform" Modifier. For the "Axis, Origin", I eyedropped a branch at the widest part of my tree. I then clicked/dragged the "Deform" value down to taper the coil (if the coil does not change, click the "<->" arrow on the "Vertex Group" field.) https://i.postimg.cc/yddNMLc5/coil-lights.jpg

Comment: The tree is probably a cone and Mugsy wants a conical spring that would follow the shape as if a thread on a reel.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the replies, but it wasn't the tip I needed to taper but the entire coil (top-to-bottom.) Fortunately, I believe I already found the solution:

With my coil selected and placed over my tree, I found a "taper" modifier as part of the "Simple deform" Modifier. For the "Axis, Origin", I eyedropped a branch at the widest part of my tree. I then clicked/dragged the "Deform" value down to taper the coil towards the top. (If the coil does not change, click the "<->" arrow on the "Vertex Group" field.)

[image: Tree with coil]