# How to create a progressive coil spring in Blender 2.82?

Tags: bezier-curves, customization, scale, screw-modifier, splines

[image: basic example of what I'm trying to do]

I've been trying to create a coil spring with a progressive elongation of the spiral in the Z direction and so far have been coming up short. Seems like it's possible to scale the radius easily enough, but not the tightness of the spiral itself.

I've primarily been using the screw modifier to achieve a basic coil.

Does anyone have any suggestions? will I need to use a particular modifier combo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Taper a coil?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159890/how-to-taper-a-coil)

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't exactly what I was looking for. I'm not trying to taper the radius of the coil itself, just progressively increase the grade of the coil. I'd actually prefer that the coil radius remain static. What I'm looking for is something like this: 
https://pasteboard.co/JcYc58w.jpg

Comment: @ltsmashGIS You should [add that image to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491). Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159890

Answer (score 3):

1. First add a vert and use the screw modifier.
   [image: Add Vert]
   [image: Screw mod]
2. Then add a lattice and scale/move it in objectmode to the correct size and location. Also subdivide it alonge the Z-Axis.

[image: Add lattice]
[image: Edit lattice]

3. After that add the lattice-modifier with the newly created lattice-object.

[image: lattice-modifier]

4. Now you can change the coil by editing the lattice-object in editmode.

[image: Edit lattice-object]

5. So I did the fast method by just adding a skin-modifier and changing the size in edit-mode with **ctrl+a**.

You can also apply the modifiers and convert it to a curve and set it to nurbse...

[image: Skin-modifier]

Answer (score 1):

Potentially make if you make the coil uniform, you can use proportional edition to move the top of it and it should expand the top more than the bottom.

Comment: I had the same thought, but can't get it to work without subdividing the lattice.