# How can I make a half circle spiral slide?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to make a shape like the picture below.

I used an Archemedian curve spiral to make a shape for the slide, because I want the upper part of the spiral to have a smaller radius than the lower part.
But now I am stuck on what to do next. I tried putting an extruded half circle on the curve, but that doesn't do anything.

So, what to do next after creating my archemedian curve spiral? (2nd picture)

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have now been able to make the shape that I want. I used an archmedian curve and converted it to a mesh. Would you know how I could cut the shape in half? I wanted to delete faces, but the faces sort of rotate as you can see in the third picture. So 'just' deleting faces is not an option.

[image]

EDIT: File [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159890/how-to-taper-a-coil

Answer (score 5):

An Archimedean Spiral primitive with the settings as below will do it:

[image]

... followed up with *Solidify* and *Bevel* modifiers. This can be converted to a mesh when you're happy.

I guess it's almost as easy to sweep a Curve Primitive > Arc along a Curve Primitive > Spiral in Geometry Nodes, for the base-object, in which case you're non-destructive all the way.

Answer (score 4):

Switch the curve to *Twist Method > Z-Up*:

[image]

It should work:

[image]

You can still play with the *Tilt* value of the control points if necessary (in the *N* panel or shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: Ah, the z-up twist method makes a huge difference! But how do you see both the mesh and curve? If I convert my curve to Mesh, the curve is gone.

Comment: Also, after I have extruded along normals, the bevel modifier is not working.

Comment: I have used a mesh that has an Array and Curve modifier, but doing it with a curve works as well, as for your bevel problem, please share your file

Comment: Can you show me how you did that? Here is the file for the bevel? I added the file

Comment: It's not clear where you want to bevel, if you want to bevel the edge, put the Bevel modifier Angle at 90°, also put the Subdivision Surface below the Bevel modifier, also maybe you want to put a Solidify modifier at the top of your modifiers stack in order to give a bit of thickness?

Comment: Also I've edited my answer and linked the file

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be to use the [`XYZ Math Surface`](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_3d_Function_Surface/) from menu *Add > Mesh > Math Function > XYZ Math Surface*:

[image]

This option uses the following [Parametric Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation), but only copy/paste the right side of the equal sign for each equation into the $X,Y,Z$ $equation$ fields:

$$x(u,v) = (b*(a+u*f)+a*\cos(v))*\cos(-u)$$
$$y(u,v) = (b*(a+u*f)+a*\cos(v))*\sin(-u)$$
$$z(u,v) = -a*(\sin(v) + u*c)$$

where `a` is the radius of the arc/tube, `b` is the tapering radius of the whole spiral setup, `f` is the tapering amount, and `c` is the height. Set $V max$ to the value of $\pi$ by typing in `pi` in that field to get half tube result. Add Solidify Modifier and then Subdivision Modifier to get this:

[image]

Comment: It does work for me to a certain degree. The only thing is - the beginning and end of the slide are also connected? Also, doing this type of math has been too long for me haha. Not really understanding what I am doing also doesn't help probably.

Comment: yeah bit tricky  i just added this solution to add more variety and some may find it useful 

Answer (score 2):

There must be an already existing answer to this somewhere… Here's one way to do it:

1. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> Edit the Default Cube.
2. With everything selected <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>, to flatten it.
3. <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> remove doubles.
4. <kbd>2</kbd> for edge selection mode, select the top edge, <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> delete it.
5. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> Object Mode.
6. <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> Subdivision Surface.
7. Add *Screw Modifier*.
8. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> Add an Empty.
9. Select the mesh object again, set the empty as the axis object of the screw modifier, increase the screw value.
10. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> Move the object on the $x$ axis.
11. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Scale the object on the $z$ axis
12. Add a *Solidify* modifier, Bevel modifier, another Subdivision modifier:

[image]

Whoops, it's not archimedean, you could create a Bezier manually and bevel it with an arc profile, but Geometry Nodes help with this part as well:

[image]

Comment: Ah I see what you are doing, could you explain a bit what the Empty does for the Screw modifier?

Comment: I want to use an archmedian curve as I mentioned, because I want to have a smaller radius of the second rotation. I added another picture. That is the shape that I want, but I need like half a circle.

Comment: @DPlayground the empty marks the vertical line, around which the screw revolves. In my answer the empty is at world origin, so the screw revolves around the world origin. You don't really need the empty, you could instead move the geometry in edit mode, away from the origin… Unfortunately I missed the "archemedian" part, so I'll post geonodes solution

Comment: Could you show what you mean with creating a bezier and bevel it with an arc profile?

Comment: Also, I don't have the Set Curve Normal Node. I am working in Blender 3.1.0 - maybe because its an older version?

Comment: @DPlayground the node is available since Blender 3.4 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/60486 look into the Robin Betts' answer.