# Curve to Mesh in 4.0

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

The link below is a screenshot of an older version of Blender. How can I create a spiral, turn it into a mesh, and control the thickness of the beginning and end of the mesh to something like in the screenshot in 4.0?

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/_images/modeling_geometry-nodes_curve_curve-parameter_example.png

[image]

Comment: exactly the same but with "spline parameter"

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/_images/modeling_geometry-nodes_curve_curve-parameter_example.png in 4.0 (in the documentation: just changed the version which is in the url)

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300548/how-can-i-make-a-half-circle-spiral-slide. just sharing this in case someone might look for something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same apart from the *Curve Parameter* which is now *Spline Parameter*. By the way this could have easily been found if you just entered "para" in the *Add* menu search because it is the only result having "Parameter" in it.

[image: spline parameter]